# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException in android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have  2 arraylist in android.

**ArrayList Name; with size 5**

**ArrayList Mobile; with size 2**

and

**Name: {A, B,C,D,E};**

**Mobile: {4,2};**

it means only two person have mobile number.

Here, I run loop 5 times but i faced **java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException**, I know mobile have not all 5 itemes so that it occures.

But how to handle this exception.

I display five name in textview and 2 mobile respective and other 3 textview of mobile hide, through on exception on catch block, IndexOutOfBoundsException .

```
try{
    for(int i=0; i< Name.size(); i++){
       name.setText(Name.get(i).toString);
       if(Mobile.get(i)!=null){
       mobile.setText(Mobile.get(i).toString);
       }else{
       mboile.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }
    }
}catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Learn about `try-catch-blocks`

Comment: You iterate Name list which size is 5 but you try to get object from mobile which size 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check if Mobile has an element at position i.
It has if his `size` is greater than i.

```
for (int i =  0; i < Name.size(); i++){
    name.setText(Name.get(i).toString);
    if (i < Mobile.size()) {
       mobile.setText(Mobile.get(i).toString);
    } else {
        mobile.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Note: format your question so it is easier to be read.

Answer (score 1):

This will fail

```
if(Mobile.get(i)!=null){
```

when `i` is greater than the length

see [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int))

> Throws: IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range
>   (index < 0 || index >= size())